# Calling a Sub (containing a Do until loop) within a IF/Else Statement

Tags: vba, subroutine

I have a `do until loop` I keep having to repeat within an `IF/ELSE` statement.I want to call a `sub` (containing the `do until loop`) inside IF/Else If/Then statements instead. Please help

This code works but I want to condense each `do until loop` into a `sub` I can call with varying `Tf` and `gain` values:

```
Dim tmin As Double  
Dim hgmin As Double
Dim tf As Double
Dim hmix As Double
Dim hg As Double
Dim i As Double
tmin = -70               'Lowest temperature of fluid on chart (Fahreinhet)
hgmin = 79.66            'Lowest enthalpy(saturated vapor)

tf = InputBox("Enter Lower Temperature [Fahrenheit]")   'Lower temperature of system

i = tmin
hg = hgmin
If tf <= -9 Then
     Do Until i = tf
        hg = hg + 0.15
        i = i + 1
    Loop
ElseIf tf >= -9 And tf <= 60 Then
    Do Until i = -9
        hg = hg + 0.15
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Do Until i = tf
        hg = hg + 0.125
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End If 
msgbox(hg)
End Sub
```

Code below does not work, either loop stuck or gives me value of `hmin` rather than `hmin + (gain * amount of iterations from tmin to Tf)`.

```
Sub main()
    Dim Tf As Double
    Dim i As Double, hg As Double, tmin As Double, hmin As Double

    Tf= InputBox("Enter Lower Temperature Value")
    hmin = 79.66

    hg = hmin
    tmin = -70
    i = tmin

    If Tf <= -9 Then
        Call subby(Tf, 0.15)

    ElseIf Tf >= -9 And Tf <= 60 Then
        Call subby(-9, 0.15)
        Call subby(Tf, 0.125)
    End If
    msgbox(hg)

End Sub

Sub subby(T As Double, gain As Double)
    Dim i As Double, hg As Double, tmin As Double, hmin As Double
    tmin = -70
    hmin = 79.66

    hg = hmin
    i = tmin
    Do Until i = T
        hg = hg + gain
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

I want the below code attempting the method to call another `sub` into the `main sub` `IF/Else` statement to match the above code values for `hg`.

Comment: Well first of all, would be simpler to just multiply those values instead of looping?! i.e.: `hg = hg + (tf * 0.15)` or very similar logic/calculation.

Comment: Seems that `subby` doesn't return anything (`hg` in `subby` is not the same variable as `hg` in `main`)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your attempt at moving to a sub is that the your variables are not visible in that sub.  I see that you tried to "fix" it by declaring those variables as locals, but then the main variables don't get changed right?

One workaround is to insert a MODULE, then declare your variables there as [PUBLIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/public-statement):

```
Public tmin As Double  
Public hgmin As Double
Public tf As Double
Public hmix As Double
Public hg As Double
Public i As Double
```

From the docs:

> Variables declared by using the Public statement are available to all
>   procedures in all modules in all applications

Be sure to get rid of those duplicate variable declarations, both inside your subby() and in main().  They should only be declared in the module.

An alternative would be to pass ALL of the variables that need to be accessed and changed into the method.  You have to decide which is easier, or better for your situation.